# Typescript: Create Function From String with Interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some logic saved in a string and I need to convert it to a runable function.  I have Interface already setup to make it strongly typed in Typescript, but it seem to not work.

```
interface IInterface {
    Run(data: string): Promise<string>;
}
let code: string = `
    return new class{
        let Run = function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            return "SUCCESS";
        };
    }
`;
let obj: IInterface = Function(code) as IInterface;
obj.Run("Test ").then((result: string ) => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Should write:  Test SUCCESS

Comment: Is that the actual text that you need to work with or you can change the syntax so that it will be real javascript?

Comment: Syntax can be changed, I just wrote some test code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you evaluate javascript stored in strings via `eval`.

```
interface IInterface {
  run(data: string): Promise<string>;
}

var f: IInterface = eval(`({run: function(data) { console.log(data); return Promise.resolve("SUCCESS"); } })`);

f.run("hello world").then(x=>console.log(x));
```

should print as you expect.